# Mi codigo no compila

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

estoy con un proyecto de pascal y la idea es que el programa pueda aceptar pagos de tres productos distintos pero no logro compilarlo, hay tres variantes, costo del agua que son 7$ costo de desodorante que son 15$ y costo de pava 25$.

codigo:

```
program Examen;
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
 var
    Mayor,Menor,Igual:boolean;
    costo,dineroingresado,agua,desodorante,pava,resto:integer;

 const costoagua=7; costodesodorante=15; costopava=25;

 begin
  writeln('Objetivo: Crear un codigo que indique dependiendo');
  write('del dinero ingresado si la compra se realizara o no.');
  writeln('');
  writeln('');
  writeln('Ingresar numero o numeros: ');
  readln;

 Mayor:= (dineroingresado > costoagua, costodesodorante, costopava) and (r > costoagua or costodesodorante or costopava);
 Menor:= (dineroingresado < costoagua, costodesodorante, costopava) and (r < costoagua or costodesodorante or costopava);
 Igual:= (dineroingresado = costoagua, costodesodorante, costopava) and (r = costoagua or costodesodorante or costopava);

 if Mayor
 then writeln('devolviendo:' (dineroingresado - costo));
 else if Menor
      then writeln('Compra rechazada');
      else if Igual
           then writeln('Compra aceptada'); readln;

 end.
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Es importante que des los máximos detalles para poder ayudarte.
Si tu programa tiene un error de compilacaión, lo más lógico es que añadas a tu pregunta cual es el error que estás obteniendo (código/descipción). Puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir información.

Comment: Por lo que veo además, tienes algunos errores en las líneas de comparación. Revisa la sintaxis de los operaciodes >, <,...  y los operadores lógicos AND/OR.
Esas líneas están escritas incorrectamente.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios errores en tu código.

- declaras la variable `dineroingresado`, pero nunca pides el valor al usuario, debes pedirlo con `read`, por ejemplo:

  ```
    read(dineroingresado);
  ```
- De sintaxis de pascal. Por ejemplo, la línea:

  > ```
  > Mayor:= (dineroingresado > costoagua, costodesodorante, costopava) and (r > costoagua or costodesodorante or costopava);
  > ```

  Y las que le siguen son totalmente incorrectas, pues los operadores `>, <, >=, <=, and, or` requieren dos operandos, uno a la izquierda y uno a la derecha. (No cero ni más de uno). Es decir, es válido poner `DineroIngresado > CostoAgua`, pero allí termina la expresión, no puedes poner más operandos con el operador `>`, a menos que conviertas esta expresión en un operando de otro operador, por ejemplo, `(DineroIngresado > CostoAgua) and (DineroIngresado > CostoDesodorante)`, y así.
- Si en esta líneas quieres saber si el dinero ingresado es *mayor* que todos, en realidad basta con saber si es mayor al producto mas caro, que es la pava, por lo que bastaría con evaluar si es mayor que eso:

  ```
  Mayor := DineroIngresado > CostoPava;
  ```
- Creo que no has desarrollado aún la idea fuera de un programa. Una de las  principales habilidades que debe tener el programador es la de *descubrir* el algorítmo detrás de las operaciones que se hacen a mano, y para ello viene muy bien realizar las operaciones en papel, no mentalmente, y *quebrar* las operaciones complejas en los pasos más simples, que involucren cálculos concretos.

  Desarrollando esta idea, yo primero vería, por ejemplo, si el dinero alcanza para comprar una pava, si alcanza, entonces ya evalúo si le debo dar cambio o no y hago el cálculo correspondiente en caso que deba darlo, imprimiendo el resultado en cada caso.

  Si no alcanza para comprar una pava, entonces ya vería si alcanza para comprar un desodorante... y así hasta terminar con el producto más barato.

  Ya si no le alcanza ni para ese, entonces imprimo al final venta no aceptada.

Una vez tienes la idea en términos como estos, ya serías capaz de escribirla en cualquier lenguaje de programación del que sepas la sintaxis.

Sugiero que avances por esta línea, y si te surgen dudas o nuevos problemas con la sintaxis, puedes siempre volver y escribir comentarios o una nueva pregunta aquí en StackOverflow.